Multiple questions on erasing data. Are they duplicates?
I was reviewing the question here: How to Erase All Data on Compaq Laptop and I found two candidates for closing as a duplicate of.
Securely erasing all data from a hard drive
or
Erase disk before selling
I also just found Secure data wipe before laptop sell, which upon reading the comments and answer, it seems the other two are outdated. What is the correct way to handle all of these questions?

If you have an opinion on which is better than the others, vote to close as that. If it's a toss up, roll a dice and then vote to close.
There are a few duplicate loops on this site where a collection of closely related questions that have similar answers but also some valid and important differences between them are all closed or flagged as duplicates of each other. While a single question with good answers would be best, it's not something easily cleaned up, and so having multiple questions all flagged as duplicates of others isn't really a problem in every case.

If it's a toss up, wouldn't you throw a coin not a die? :P

I've always believed some height to the dice throw helps. Catching it on my wrist is arguably more difficult, but still, once mastered, tossing up the die is far better for handling decisions greater than binary. :P
